# Keep the selected radio button checked and clicked upon page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

i have a radio input whose values are coming dynamically and creating multiple radio fields. Long list of radio fields are displayed.

```
<?php
 for ($i = 0; $i < $total_trades; $i++) {
 $array_trade_data = $data_trade_data[$i];
 $Trade_name = $array_trade_data['name'];
 $Trade_id = $array_trade_data['id'];

?>

<input type="radio" class="trade" id="<?php echo $Trade_id; ?>" name="trade" value="<?php echo $Trade_id; ?>" ><?php echo $Trade_name; ?><br>

 <?php } ?>
```

I want to Keep the selected radio button checked and clicked upon page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you cold use checked attribute

```html
    <input type="radio" name="trade">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="trade" checked>2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="trade">3
```

to click something like

```
<script>document.getelementbyid("<?php echo $Trade_id; ?>").click();</script>
```

Comment: I dont want to used checked attribute as all the options starts showing checked in html. or the last option gets checked in the form. fields of my form are being created dynamically from one line of input field.